# Conditional Formatting within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am looking for some help on how to make my data easily changeable with colours depending on what is in a specific cell.

Here is a example sheet

[Example Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GCqlCG31fh-1TSlueUItAZwHbRKABeEtpHEjKpGqhyw/edit?usp=sharing)

So basically I want to make it so when I put a Y in column C that it then turns A2, B2 and C2 to green, and so on for N, C and NN.

But it has to be specific too those two cells and not the whole row

Answer (score -1):

This is possible. I cannot open your sheet, so unable to see what you exactly mean.
But I think you mean something like in my example.

See printscreen below. Edit:
Cannot post images untill 10 reputation points.

Also added the link to my example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q21eEGJoicqWy1hUEroYak3NErRRh0CVop3wXR6mzR8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thankyou for this. You will be able to edit the sheet now as the first one was from my business account but now have swapped it to my personal account with read access.

Comment: I made column A and B green when column C is Y. You can edit the conditional format to your liking.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see the formatting as the sheet is currently view only

Comment: I did it in your Example sheet.